# array_search to remove value not removing index [0]

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm trying to remove items by value from an array, it works perfectly, except for the value stored in index `[0]`. Here is the code:

```
if(($key = array_search($_REQUEST['id_remove'], $_SESSION['carrito'])) !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION['carrito'][$key]);
}
```

Any ideas of why it is not working for the value stored on index `[0]`?

Comment: Well what is the value of pos[0] and what is the search value from request?

Comment: [Works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f420d336b6d5b918688482d9c27cf1a12fed5a9) for me...

Comment: The value of pos[0] is an int, the request brings the id of an item previously printed on an input hidden form. It works perfectly with all the pos[1-infinite] except for the pos[0].

Comment: Obviously it does work as shown in the Works link.

Comment: your code is correct and it will must work.

Comment: [Works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61fd5ce26b074282e4d5506b9077a46275433726) with strings also.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I noticed the problem is not the php function, for some reason the for on the previous page is not printing the <form> on the first div. I have no idea why, but I'll keep you posted. Again, thank you.